# I suddenly can't initialize a react-native app, although it has worked before

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I ran "npx react-native init Test"

```
 Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
ℹ Installing dependencies
✔ CocoaPods (https://cocoapods.org/) is not installed. CocoaPods is necessary for the iOS project to run correctly. Do you want to install it? › Yes, with Homebrew
✔ Installing CocoaPods
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
```

but CocoaPods is installed:
pod --version returns 1.11.3

react-native version is 8.0.6

Answer (score 0):

If you are using M1 or up processor, try updating `ruby` and again install cocoapods or you can go into iOS folder and do `pod install`

I possible please share whole error from terminal.

Thanks :)